# How can I customize the directory of my own style files for latex on MAC-OS?

Tags: installing, paths, texmf

I couldn't find any satisfying solution to this problem I had for years so I finally decided to ask it myself.

I want to create a folder outside the usual latex directories (e.g. /Users/myname/Dropbox/tex-style) and put my own me.sty files in that folder. The goal is when I import these new .sty files, I can directly write

```
\usepackage{me}
```

instead of writing

```
\usepackage{/Users/myname/Dropbox/tex-style/me}
```

I have tried many things, including adding a new path `/Users/myname/Dropbox/tex-style` to TEXMFHOME in texmf.cnf. Then I tried `kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFHOME` and the new directory does show up. But when I compiled my latex file, it still couldn't find me.sty. How can I do such things for TexLive on MAC-OS?

I found the above proposal in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/where-do-i-place-my-own-sty-or-cls-files-to-make-them-available-to-all-my-te/1167?newreg=2722bd093c64417081c1766c4d9c48c1). But it doesn't work for me as described above. Please help!

Thanks in advance!

I do not understand why my question is closed. The link does not answer my question as it is about Windows system. My question is about MacOS.

Comment: I don't think so... that link is for windows. I did try `kpsewhich --var-value=TEXMFLOCAL` in my terminal and it DOES return the folder I wanted. However, latex still does not compile and outputs error "cannot find .sty file"